# The custom hook is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to create a SessionProvider to avoid propdrilling and hold session globally for my components.

But it is saying useSession is not a function, what gives?

```
contexts\SessionContext.js: TypeError: (0 , _hooks_useSession__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useSession) is not a function
```

My custom hook (useSession.js):

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function useSession(isLoggedInState) {

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedInState);

    return { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, }
}

export default useSession;
```

My provider (SessionContext.js):

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useSession } from '../hooks/useSession'

const SessionContext = createContext();

function SessionProvider({ children, isLoggedin = false }) {

    const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useSession(isLoggedin);

    return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}>{children}</SessionContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { SessionProvider, SessionContext };
```

I've wrapped my application using  in _app.js and then in Home (index.js) I try to use it there:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, TextContainer } from 'react-md'

import { useContext } from "react";
import { SessionContext } from "../contexts/SessionContext";

export default function Home() {

  const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useContext(SessionContext);

  return (

    <TextContainer>
      <Text type="headline-4">Hello, world!</Text>
    </TextContainer> 
  )
}
```

Anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the way your "useSession" hook is imported in the SessionContext.js.

It should be imported like this (without curly brackets) since you are exporting it as a default component.

```
import useSession from '../hooks/useSession'
```

Comment: I get setIsLoggedIn(true); is not a function, what gives?

Answer (score 1):

There are few places where you've done some mistakes.

first one is in `SessionContext.js`. In here, you're importing `useSession` as a variable import where, you've export `useSession` as default export from `useSession.js` file.
So fix this one

```js
// SessionContext.js
import useSession from '../hooks/useSession'
...
```

And second one is: you can't use `useContext(SessionContext)` there because your Home component is not a children of `SessionProvider`.
So Yo need to wrap your `home component` by `SessionProvider`.

Here is the fix code:

```js
// index.js

import { SessionContext, SessionProvider } from "../contexts/SessionContext";

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <Home />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useContext(SessionContext);
  return (
    <TextContainer>
      <Text type="headline-4">Hello, world!</Text>
    </TextContainer> 
  )
}

export default main
```